# Translations with more than one quantifier

Tags: logic

I've been having trouble translating statements with multiple quantifiers, and I would like some feedback and advice on my answers for the following translations. Let $Kxy$ mean '$x\operatorname{knows} y$'.

> Some know all who know Alma: $\exists x \forall y (Kxy\wedge Kya)$

> Some know all who know themselves: $\exists x \forall y(Kxy\wedge Kyy)$

> All who know Alma know themselves: $\forall x(Kxa\rightarrow Kxx)$

Also, there are two more which have just left me stumped. They are as follows,

> Anyone who knows everyone Alma knows knows Alma

> Everyone who knows everyone Alma knows knows someone who knows Alma.

These last two not only seem difficult to me, but also grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I don't think that is a translation, but more of an interpretation.

Comment: Your translations look good, accept in the last you want $$\forall x(Kxa\rightarrow Kxx)$$

Comment: Thank you amWhy, I actually had that written down, but typed it differently lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

To handle something like “Anyone who knows everyone Alma knows knows Alma”, break it into smaller pieces. Suppose we had a predicate $S(x)$ which expresses “$x$ knows everyone Alma knows”.  Then “Anyone who knows everyone Alma knows knows Alma” becomes “Any $x$ for which $S(x)$ is true, knows Alma”:

$$\forall x. S(x)\implies Kxa$$

Now figure out how to express $S(x)$, and insert it into the previous formula in place of $S(x)$.

Comment: Okay,so I'm not sure if I completely follow you, but here is a shot. $\forall x \forall y [(Kxy\wedge Kay)\rightarrow Kxa]$